# Get Asterisk Meetme channel / room statuses

Tags: asterisk

With the Asterisk Manager API (AMI) it's possible to accomplish a few operations on channels and on the conference room, but is it possible to get the statuses of all those operations at any given time?

For example, if I mute a channel, I get no result, which is ok, but since the admin can also control the channel via his/her phone, how can I get the status at any given time? I know I can get the status of who's talking using the `meetme list` command, but what about

1. if the channel is locked / unlocked
2. <del>if a channel (user) is mute / unmute</del>

Is it even possible?

*Note : I also posted this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820177/get-asterisk-meetme-channel-room-statuses), sorry for the duplicate*

** **Update** **

2) one can know if a user is mute when listing users in a conference room. For example :

```
1!5551112222!MASKA***!SIP/Metaswitch-000xxxxx!1!!!!0!00:43:44
....
1!5551112222!MASKA***!SIP/Metaswitch-000xxxxx!1!!1!!-1!00:43:25    <-- mute
```

**note**: I still don't know what are all the fields in this response, does anybody know?

** **Update** **

It *seems* that `meetme list` should list all conferences, and probably return their status and all, unfortunately, Trixbox CE only support Aterisk 1.6.0.26 (so it seems) and there is a [ticket](https://issues.asterisk.org/view.php?id=15926) describing that the last command is broken for that version. Seeing how often trixbox is updated, I don't expect a fix for that soon... we'll have to make do with what we got. Yet still, if anyone know some way around this to get the missing information, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are AMI interface, which allow to listen to EVENTS.

so u can create listener and remember state.

also u can use

```
  meetme list concise conf_no
```

but sorry, i not remmember if it shwo muted state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. yes, my last edits describe how it is possible to get mute states per users in a specified conference room. I was also considering events, however it is a PHP script that's connecting to AMI, and listening to events is not really workable without having a third party script that continually listens to the manager... So this is why having state on demand is highly if not the only preferable solution in our case at the moment.

Comment: i recomend use AMI. becuase "state  on demand" become weird when load is hi.

Answer (score 0):

With a clear head this morning, I read the [documentation](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cli+show+conferences) once again. And finally tried the only command I haven't yet tried before

```
meetme
```

simply that returns all the active conferences, and

```
meetme concise
```

returns them all in a `!` separated list. Problem solved!

<del>Now, all I need to figure out is the AMI [3 seconds response delay problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/293982/asterisk-manager-interface-response-delay/293998#293998)...</del>