# Asterisk Manager Interface response delay

Tags: asterisk

When connecting to the Asterisk Manager via a socket (telnet style), there is a 3 second delay after each commands. Is this normal? Why is it so? Can a response be returned immediately?

** **EDIT** **

some more info

- the manager is a closed test environment server
- there are at most 4 uers connected at once
- it is installed on a physical enterprise server machine using the most recent trixbox CE
- all DNS seems properly setup (SSH works fine without delays)
- all commands are executed sending a `\r\n` for line breaks, plus an extra `\r\n` at the end.

  For example :

  ```
  Action: Command{\r\n}
  Command: meetme list 204 concise{\r\n}
  {\r\n}
  ```

  **note** : `{\r\n}` are really carriage returns and new line feed characters, and not a literal string, to avoid confusion and show what's being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, somewhere deep inside the code we use to communicate with the AMI server, there was some construct that added a [wait timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) before every IO operation. After modifying the code quite a bit, I managed to remove that "feature" and everything is now running normal"

Answer (score 0):

Does the AMI have a three second delay because the Asterisk server is very busy?

Is the network connection between the client and server lag-free, or does it have its own lag?

Is the client system free of lag?

The most likely cause is that the Asterisk server is very busy, and is responding when the command reaches the front of the queued commands.

Do you have more information?

Comment: the Asterisk server is a test environment, and has at most 4 connected users at once. Also, it is on a closed network (behind a firewall) and all DNS are set up correctly both ways. I should have mentioned that. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

try put end of line(or press enter) twice, as requested by specification ;)

Comment: ... that... may be the case. I'll try that in the morrow.

Comment: nope, the script sends `\r\n\r\n` after each commands (using `\r\n` as new line characters)

Comment: any buffering in script? try do same via telnet. and see if issue exist

Comment: see my response